# Sending a CSV from JavaScript to Firebase Cloud Storage

Tags: javascript, csv, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm trying to send a CSV into Firebase Cloud Storage but not from the user manually selecting the file from their file explorer. Rather, on the click of a button, a CSV file will be created in JavaScript and this is what I want to upload to Cloud Storage.

The code snippet shows how I'm creating the file

```js
function sendToCloudStore() {
  const rows = [["name1", "city1", "some other info"], ["name2", "city2", "more info"]];
      let csvContent = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,";
      rows.forEach(function(rowArray){
      let row = rowArray.join(",");
      csvContent += row + "\r\n";
      }); 
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Click Me" onclick="sendToCloudStore()">
```

But I don't know how I get this into Storage. I thought doing this:

```
storageRef.child('path/to/CSV').put(csvContent)
```

Would do the trick but it returns the following error

```
{code_: "storage/invalid-argument", message_: "Firebase Storage: Invalid argument in `put` at index 0: Expected Blob or File.", serverResponse_: null, name_: "FirebaseError"}
```

Can anybody tell me how I can upload this file directly in the same button click action?

Many thanks,

George

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling [`put()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Reference#put), and it's telling you that it's expecting either a File or a Blob object.  But you're passing it a string.  If you want to upload a string, use the [`putString()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Reference#putString) method instead.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you such an easy fix